# Downloading array as file

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and passing information from the controller to the view using:

```
 $this->load->view('myview', $data);
```

$data is an array and defined as:

```
$data['people'] = ....
```

In my view, as display people as

```
foreach($people as $person) {

echo $person->name . " " . $person->email;

}
```

I then have a file which takes an array of 'person' objects and creates a csv file based on it.

In my view, I have a link to such file and would like to pass the $people array over to it.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSV file by using array and make it as downloadable file with path in view.

Ref [this](http://webtricksandtreats.com/export-to-csv-php/)

OR

You can use generate table in html and convert to csv by using javascript

Ref [This](https://gist.github.com/adilapapaya/9787842)

Comment: Yes, but if the user doesn't want to download the csv then it is created for nothing and just uses up server resources.

Comment: Thanks, but the iCal is generated by a CI controller, so I would need to redirect to /icalgenerator and somehow pass the array to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array in the link in **not feasible** and **its weird**.
I would recommend you to pass **`id`** of a particular person in the link 
and then
get the data of that person by **querying** the database again.

**For example:**

**Controller**

```
class People extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('people_model');
    }

    public function people()
    {
        $data['people'] = $this->people_model->get_people();
        $this->load->view('myview', $data);
    }

    public function person_detail($person_id)
    {
        $person = $this->people_model->get_person($person_id);

        // Now you have that person's detail
        // Do whatever you want

        // Write in a file
        file_put_contents('filename.txt', print_r($person, true));
    }
}
```

**View (myview.php)**

```
<table>

<?php foreach($people as $person) { ?>
<tr>
<td><a href="/people/person_detail/{$person->id}"><?php echo $person->id ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo $person->name ?></td>
<td><?php echo $person->email ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```